# Puting <div>s next to each other

Tags: html

I have been searching for a way to put divs next to eachother and found one that "worked" but there is an issue

```
float: left;
```

it worked!  but it also popped them out of the parent div and it looks silly.  the background of the parent div no longer cares about them.

How can I put two divs, side by side, while in another div?

Comment: Change the div to a span as the easiest soln. The two are functionally same div is a block element and span is non-block. Of course you can go the style route to make div's float.

Comment: Tried span...with and without float.  Same results =(

Answer (score 1):

Remove your float and try :

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating elements doesn't normally affect the size of their parent. You can change this by changing the `overflow` style of the parent.

Example:

```css
.parent { background: red; overflow: hidden; }
.child { float: left; margin: 5px; background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child 1</div>
  <div class="child">child 2</div>
  <div class="child">child 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this...same results.  the controls are floating outside of the parent div.

Comment: @AlexKosmač: Hm... that shouldn't be possible. Check that you set overflow on the parent, and that the floating elements actually are children.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent floated blocks from "popping out" of the parent container, you need to trigger a block-formatting context, which you can do by specifying:

```
overflow: auto
```

for the parent container.

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  background-color: beige;
  overflow: auto;
}
.wrap div {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
</div>
```